# Is $\int (e^{dx} - 1) = x + c$ legal?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was cooking and made up this integral.
$$\int (e^{dx} - 1) = x+ c,$$
where $c$ is some constant.

My reasoning for the above equality goes like this: expand $e^{dx}$ in a series and subtract from $1$ so that we have a series of differentials,
$$e^{dx} - 1 = dx + \dfrac{(dx)^2}{2!} + \cdots,$$
and integrating this gives
$$\int (e^{dx} - 1) = \int dx + \int\dfrac{(dx)^2}{2!} + \cdots = \int dx + \int\dfrac{dx}{2!}\cdot dx+\cdots = x + c.$$
I know this is not rigorous. But is it possible? What field of math would this kind of problem, where the $dx$'s are contained in functions, belong to? This might just be a quick question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you wrote can be made rigorous and make sense. The field of math is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra where you can treat quantities like $dx$ as formal symbols belonging in an abstract algebraic structure. Here $dx$ would be considered an algebraic $1$-form, as opposed to the analytic $1$-forms described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form

Comment: What do you mean by $\int\dfrac{(dx)^2}{2!}$ (or by $\int\dfrac{dx}{2!}\cdot dx$)?

Comment: Not related, but what were you cooking?

Comment: @LordVader007. May be, some exotic mushrooms ! (just kidding)

Comment: @LordVader007 Integrals!

Comment: @Mirko I pretended that the differential was an infinitesimal (and thus constant) which is then independent of the integral and can be taken out. Something like that.

Comment: @pre-kidney Awesome! Glad to know that this has a name.